# How can I make or where to find muscles that stretch similar to this video

Tags: modeling

I want to make my own workout videos with an animated model of muscles stretching and bending over my real muscles that look accurate to the raw footage similar to this.

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/yURXU8LJK88

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.